# problem with while loop

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

here is the script I wrote but it seems it has problem with while ! while suppose to compare the content of K with SDATE and while they are not equal go to the loop !

```
for d in \
 $(sed -nre 's/.*\[(..)\/(...)\/(....):(..:..:..) .*/\1 \2 \3 \4/p' thttpd.log | date +%s -f-);
do echo $d >s1; done

time=$(expr 60 \* 60 \* 24 \* 5)
EDATE=`tail -1 s1`
SDATE=$[$EDATE - $time]
time=$(expr 60 \* 60 \* 24 \* 5)
EDATE=`tail -1 s1`
SDATE=$[$EDATE - $time]
k=`tail -1 s1`
echo $k
echo $SDATE
while [$k -ne $SDATE](k and SDATE contain numbers)
 do
k=`tail -1 s1`
sed '1d' < s1 > tempfile
mv s1 s1.old
mv tempfile s1
echo $K| awk '{print strftime("%d/%m/%Y:%T",$1)}'|tee -a ass

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have spaces around `[` or `]`. Which causes BASH to parse the line incorrectly.

With the following line, BASH will attempt to run the program `[$K`, probably not what you are intending.
`while [$k -ne $SDATE]`

What you need to have is the following:
`while [ $k -ne $SDATE ]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while [[ $k != $SDATE ]]
```

Comment: still has problem ! k is 1041454521
SDATE is 1041022521 and the error 
./10: line 14: [[1041454521: command not found

Comment: One bracket would be sufficient. The important thing is the space after [ and before ]. [ is another way to write "test", like: while test "$k" != "$DATE" ; do ...

Comment: Hmm. I was always taught to use two brackets, because `[[` is guaranteed to be a builtin, whereas `[` might be an external program (and thus slower). And there were some other subtleties that I forgot.

Comment: still has problem ! it's gonna kill me till run properly ! :((( 31/12/1969:16:00:00
./10: line 14: [: -ne: unary operator expected
it gives me the wrong date ! it's suppose to be 2003 not 1969

Comment: I didn't write `-ne` anywhere.

Comment: @matarsak: .ne is for numbers only. Please put your variables into "" like "$k", they might be empty. What does your code look like now?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, shell programming is so touchy...

```
k=0
while [ $k != 4 ]; do echo $k; k=`expr $k + 1`; done
```

Works and prints 0, 1, 2, 3 on separate lines as expected and this essentially looks like what you have except for spaces, newlines, and sources of values. Maybe it is a string versus value problem but I did not think shell variables had types.

I would try stripping what you have back until it works then add back what you want it to do.

Comment: p.s. I also noticed on your third from last line (with the awk) it is `$K` instead of `$k`. Shell variables are case sensitive.